# cygwin unzip is creating dir/files that I cannot delete later

Tags: permissions, filesystems, cygwin, acl, unzip

UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP -- from cygwin 32-bit.

Windows 7 Enterprise. Run with Administrator access. When I use unzip to explode .zip files, the directories and files that are created by unzip cannot be deleted later on. I can explore the created directory structure and view the nodes (files) -- however, I cannot delete any of the directories or the files. What gives ? this is proving to be expensive and painful!

I get the error "Access is denied" when I run the command "rd /s /q dir".

However, if I use 7-Zip File Manager for extracting, I can later delete the files and directories without issues. So, unzip is setting some permissions on the files that prevent it from being deleted.

So what is the solution ? How can I tell unzip to assign the right permissions. Also, for existing directory trees (that were created by unzip), how can I remove the existing permissions so I can delete the directory trees ?

There seems to be parallels with : [How do I stop cygwin from creating undeletable files? Or can I delete them somehow?](https://superuser.com/questions/1076539/how-do-i-stop-cygwin-from-creating-undeletable-files-or-can-i-delete-them-someh)

Comment: What does `rm -r dir` run as Admin ? Check file permission with icacls .

Comment: rm -r dir did the trick! thank you. Please add an answer and I will select it. thank you. It would also be great if you could say why rd /s /q did not solve it. What tools can I use to understand what is happening under the layers ? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cygwin creates dedicated crafted ACLs to mimic POSIX permission,
the couterpart to create files and directories with cygwin unzip 
is to remove then with cygwin `rm -r dir`

Eventually run it as Admin.

The Windows command `icacls` allows to verify file and directory ACLs in details.